# Maven-Release with Jenkins: Skip second test run

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

We use Jenkins (2.150.1) together [with M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin) (0.14.0). After checkout from git we specified "Maven release build -> Release goals and options"

```
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules -Dgoals=deploy
```

and in the Build step we configured the maven "Goals and Options"

```
clean verify -U
```

When we start to perform a Maven release, I get asked e.g. a Release Version 1.0 and a new Version 1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Generally, everything works fine like the following way:

- git clone
- mvn changes versions to 1.0
- mvn clean verify -U
- mvn release perform
- mvn changes version to 1.1-SNAPSHOT
- mvn clean verify -U
- mvn release perform

**Question:** Do you know how I can skip the second part? So maven does update to Version 1.1-SNAPSHOT but does NOT perform the following two steps?